# golang json array unmarshal into type struct

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

What is causing this to not break apart json?  Anyone have an idea on how type is wrong?

With error of:

> {"Rates":[{"Symbol":"EURAUD","Bid":"1.45492","Ask":"1.45608","Spread":"11.60","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"Copper","Bid":"2.6068","Ask":"2.6088","Spread":"2.00","ProductType":"3",},{"Symbol":"AUDNZD","Bid":"1.08999","Ask":"1.09177","Spread":"17.80","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"EURSEK","Bid":"9.63786","Ask":"9.65569","Spread":"178.30","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"CADJPY","Bid":"81.629","Ask":"81.708","Spread":"7.90","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"USDCHF","Bid":"0.99463","Ask":"0.99527","Spread":"6.40","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"USDCNH","Bid":"6.8973","Ask":"6.8993","Spread":"20.00","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"US30","Bid":"20950.00","Ask":"20952.00","Spread":"2.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"XAGUSD","Bid":"17.202","Ask":"17.25","Spread":"4.80","ProductType":"5",},{"Symbol":"USDSEK","Bid":"8.84794","Ask":"8.85542","Spread":"74.80","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"AUDCHF","Bid":"0.74417","Ask":"0.74588","Spread":"17.10","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"GER30","Bid":"12431.05","Ask":"12433.45","Spread":"2.40","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"USOil","Bid":"49.16","Ask":"49.21","Spread":"5.00","ProductType":"3",},{"Symbol":"GBPNZD","Bid":"1.88546","Ask":"1.88762","Spread":"21.60","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"EURCAD","Bid":"1.48748","Ask":"1.48893","Spread":"14.50","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"EURUSD","Bid":"1.08977","Ask":"1.08997","Spread":"2.00","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"AUS200","Bid":"5922.00","Ask":"5924.00","Spread":"2.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"EURJPY","Bid":"121.512","Ask":"121.57","Spread":"5.80","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"EURGBP","Bid":"0.84132","Ask":"0.84208","Spread":"7.60","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"EURNOK","Bid":"9.34136","Ask":"9.36364","Spread":"222.80","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"USDCAD","Bid":"1.36524","Ask":"1.36588","Spread":"6.40","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"GBPCHF","Bid":"1.28753","Ask":"1.28922","Spread":"16.90","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"GBPAUD","Bid":"1.72838","Ask":"1.7303","Spread":"19.20","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"USDJPY","Bid":"111.51","Ask":"111.537","Spread":"2.70","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"USDNOK","Bid":"8.57607","Ask":"8.58684","Spread":"107.70","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"AUDCAD","Bid":"1.02173","Ask":"1.02347","Spread":"17.40","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"FRA40","Bid":"5259.60","Ask":"5267.30","Spread":"7.70","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"AUDUSD","Bid":"0.74858","Ask":"0.74899","Spread":"4.10","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"USDHKD","Bid":"7.77769","Ask":"7.77956","Spread":"18.70","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"NZDCHF","Bid":"0.68192","Ask":"0.68406","Spread":"21.40","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"EURTRY","Bid":"3.86851","Ask":"3.87478","Spread":"62.70","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"AUDJPY","Bid":"83.469","Ask":"83.543","Spread":"7.40","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"USDZAR","Bid":"13.3464","Ask":"13.3941","Spread":"477.00","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"Bund","Bid":"161.78","Ask":"161.81","Spread":"3.00","ProductType":"4",},{"Symbol":"USDMXN","Bid":"18.81249","Ask":"18.83178","Spread":"192.90","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"USDTRY","Bid":"3.54925","Ask":"3.5536","Spread":"43.50","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"USDOLLAR","Bid":"12232.00","Ask":"12237.00","Spread":"5.00","ProductType":"7",},{"Symbol":"JPN225","Bid":"19195.00","Ask":"19205.00","Spread":"10.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"UK100","Bid":"7197.80","Ask":"7198.90","Spread":"1.10","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"HKG33","Bid":"24650.00","Ask":"24655.00","Spread":"5.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"CADCHF","Bid":"0.72748","Ask":"0.72979","Spread":"23.10","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"NAS100","Bid":"5582.80","Ask":"5583.80","Spread":"1.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"NGAS","Bid":"3.2645","Ask":"3.2755","Spread":"11.00","ProductType":"3",},{"Symbol":"ZARJPY","Bid":"8.323","Ask":"8.361","Spread":"3.80","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"GBPCAD","Bid":"1.76724","Ask":"1.76912","Spread":"18.80","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"ESP35","Bid":"10712.00","Ask":"10720.00","Spread":"8.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"GBPUSD","Bid":"1.29452","Ask":"1.29527","Spread":"7.50","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"SPX500","Bid":"2384.18","Ask":"2384.68","Spread":"5.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"GBPJPY","Bid":"144.336","Ask":"144.448","Spread":"11.20","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"EUSTX50","Bid":"3554.00","Ask":"3555.00","Spread":"1.00","ProductType":"2",},{"Symbol":"TRYJPY","Bid":"31.378","Ask":"31.44","Spread":"6.20","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"NZDCAD","Bid":"0.93642","Ask":"0.93862","Spread":"22.00","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"EURNZD","Bid":"1.58644","Ask":"1.58916","Spread":"27.20","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"XAUUSD","Bid":"1267.79","Ask":"1268.26","Spread":"47.00","ProductType":"5",},{"Symbol":"NZDUSD","Bid":"0.68587","Ask":"0.68692","Spread":"10.50","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"NZDJPY","Bid":"76.489","Ask":"76.607","Spread":"11.80","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"UKOil","Bid":"51.84","Ask":"51.89","Spread":"5.00","ProductType":"3",},{"Symbol":"CHFJPY","Bid":"112.02","Ask":"112.148","Spread":"12.80","ProductType":"1",},{"Symbol":"EURCHF","Bid":"1.08416","Ask":"1.08459","Spread":"4.30","ProductType":"1",}]}
>   {"Rates":[{"Symbol":"EURAUD","Bid":"1.45492","Ask":"1.45608","Spread":"11.60","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"Copper","Bid":"2.6068","Ask":"2.6088","Spread":"2.00","ProductType":"3"},{"Symbol":"AUDNZD","Bid":"1.08999","Ask":"1.09177","Spread":"17.80","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"EURSEK","Bid":"9.63786","Ask":"9.65569","Spread":"178.30","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"CADJPY","Bid":"81.629","Ask":"81.708","Spread":"7.90","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"USDCHF","Bid":"0.99463","Ask":"0.99527","Spread":"6.40","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"USDCNH","Bid":"6.8973","Ask":"6.8993","Spread":"20.00","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"US30","Bid":"20950.00","Ask":"20952.00","Spread":"2.00","ProductType":"2"},{"Symbol":"XAGUSD","Bid":"17.202","Ask":"17.25","Spread":"4.80","ProductType":"5"},{"Symbol":"USDSEK","Bid":"8.84794","Ask":"8.85542","Spread":"74.80","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"AUDCHF","Bid":"0.74417","Ask":"0.74588","Spread":"17.10","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"GER30","Bid":"12431.05","Ask":"12433.45","Spread":"2.40","ProductType":"2"},{"Symbol":"USOil","Bid":"49.16","Ask":"49.21","Spread":"5.00","ProductType":"3"},{"Symbol":"GBPNZD","Bid":"1.88546","Ask":"1.88762","Spread":"21.60","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"EURCAD","Bid":"1.48748","Ask":"1.48893","Spread":"14.50","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"EURUSD","Bid":"1.08977","Ask":"1.08997","Spread":"2.00","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"AUS200","Bid":"5922.00","Ask":"5924.00","Spread":"2.00","ProductType":"2"},{"Symbol":"EURJPY","Bid":"121.512","Ask":"121.57","Spread":"5.80","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"EURGBP","Bid":"0.84132","Ask":"0.84208","Spread":"7.60","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"EURNOK","Bid":"9.34136","Ask":"9.36364","Spread":"222.80","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"USDCAD","Bid":"1.36524","Ask":"1.36588","Spread":"6.40","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"GBPCHF","Bid":"1.28753","Ask":"1.28922","Spread":"16.90","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"GBPAUD","Bid":"1.72838","Ask":"1.7303","Spread":"19.20","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"USDJPY","Bid":"111.51","Ask":"111.537","Spread":"2.70","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"USDNOK","Bid":"8.57607","Ask":"8.58684","Spread":"107.70","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"AUDCAD","Bid":"1.02173","Ask":"1.02347","Spread":"17.40","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"FRA40","Bid":"5259.60","Ask":"5267.30","Spread":"7.70","ProductType":"2"},{"Symbol":"AUDUSD","Bid":"0.74858","Ask":"0.74899","Spread":"4.10","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"USDHKD","Bid":"7.77769","Ask":"7.77956","Spread":"18.70","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"NZDCHF","Bid":"0.68192","Ask":"0.68406","Spread":"21.40","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"EURTRY","Bid":"3.86851","Ask":"3.87478","Spread":"62.70","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"AUDJPY","Bid":"83.469","Ask":"83.543","Spread":"7.40","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"USDZAR","Bid":"13.3464","Ask":"13.3941","Spread":"477.00","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"Bund","Bid":"161.78","Ask":"161.81","Spread":"3.00","ProductType":"4"},{"Symbol":"USDMXN","Bid":"18.81249","Ask":"18.83178","Spread":"192.90","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"USDTRY","Bid":"3.54925","Ask":"3.5536","Spread":"43.50","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"USDOLLAR","Bid":"12232.00","Ask":"12237.00","Spread":"5.00","ProductType":"7"},{"Symbol":"JPN225","Bid":"19195.00","Ask":"19205.00","Spread":"10.00","ProductType":"2"},{"Symbol":"UK100","Bid":"7197.80","Ask":"7198.90","Spread":"1.10","ProductType":"2"},{"Symbol":"HKG33","Bid":"24650.00","Ask":"24655.00","Spread":"5.00","ProductType":"2"},{"Symbol":"CADCHF","Bid":"0.72748","Ask":"0.72979","Spread":"23.10","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"NAS100","Bid":"5582.80","Ask":"5583.80","Spread":"1.00","ProductType":"2"},{"Symbol":"NGAS","Bid":"3.2645","Ask":"3.2755","Spread":"11.00","ProductType":"3"},{"Symbol":"ZARJPY","Bid":"8.323","Ask":"8.361","Spread":"3.80","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"GBPCAD","Bid":"1.76724","Ask":"1.76912","Spread":"18.80","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"ESP35","Bid":"10712.00","Ask":"10720.00","Spread":"8.00","ProductType":"2"},{"Symbol":"GBPUSD","Bid":"1.29452","Ask":"1.29527","Spread":"7.50","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"SPX500","Bid":"2384.18","Ask":"2384.68","Spread":"5.00","ProductType":"2"},{"Symbol":"GBPJPY","Bid":"144.336","Ask":"144.448","Spread":"11.20","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"EUSTX50","Bid":"3554.00","Ask":"3555.00","Spread":"1.00","ProductType":"2"},{"Symbol":"TRYJPY","Bid":"31.378","Ask":"31.44","Spread":"6.20","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"NZDCAD","Bid":"0.93642","Ask":"0.93862","Spread":"22.00","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"EURNZD","Bid":"1.58644","Ask":"1.58916","Spread":"27.20","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"XAUUSD","Bid":"1267.79","Ask":"1268.26","Spread":"47.00","ProductType":"5"},{"Symbol":"NZDUSD","Bid":"0.68587","Ask":"0.68692","Spread":"10.50","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"NZDJPY","Bid":"76.489","Ask":"76.607","Spread":"11.80","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"UKOil","Bid":"51.84","Ask":"51.89","Spread":"5.00","ProductType":"3"},{"Symbol":"CHFJPY","Bid":"112.02","Ask":"112.148","Spread":"12.80","ProductType":"1"},{"Symbol":"EURCHF","Bid":"1.08416","Ask":"1.08459","Spread":"4.30","ProductType":"1"}]}
>
> panic: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type
>   main.MsgRatesArray
>
> goroutine 1 [running]:
>
> main.main()
>
> ```
>     /tmp/test.go:50 +0x52c
> ```

With this code:

```
package main

import (
        "log"
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
        "bytes"
        "io/ioutil"
        "strings"
        "github.com/pquerna/ffjson/ffjson"
)


type MsgRatesArray struct {
        RateQuote []MsgRateQuoteJson `json:"Rates"`
}
type MsgRateQuoteJson struct {
        SymbolName string `json:"Symbol"`
        SymbolBid int64 `json:"Bid"`
        SymbolAsk int64 `json:"Ask"`
        SymbolSpread int64 `json:"Spread"`
        SymbolPT string `json:"ProductType"`
}

var respBytes []byte

func main() {
    var msg MsgRatesArray
    response,err := http.Get("https://ratesjson.fxcm.com/DataDisplayer")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()
    respBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    //Get bad JSON into string
    jsonBytes := respBytes[bytes.Index(respBytes, []byte("{")):bytes.LastIndex(respBytes, []byte("}"))+1]
    jsonString := string(jsonBytes)
    fmt.Println(jsonString)
    // Use a positive number to indicate max replacement count to fix bad JSON string so we can remove comma in JSON ARRAY.
    result := strings.Replace(jsonString, "\",}", "\"}", -1)
    fmt.Println(result)
    // Turn GOOD JSON string back to JSON BYTES (BIN)
    jsonBytes2, err := ffjson.Marshal(result)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // Parse JSON !
    err = ffjson.Unmarshal(jsonBytes2, &msg)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

What is wrong with type for json array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the returned json `Bid`, `Ask`, and `Spread` are json strings not integers, so change your type definition to this:

```
type MsgRateQuoteJson struct {
    SymbolName   string `json:"Symbol"`
    SymbolBid    string `json:"Bid"`
    SymbolAsk    string `json:"Ask"`
    SymbolSpread string `json:"Spread"`
    SymbolPT     string `json:"ProductType"`
}
```

And marshaling a json string to get json bytes is not the correct way, just convert the string to a byte slice like this:

```
jsonBytes2 := []byte(result)
```

... and you're good to go:

```
// Parse JSON !
err = ffjson.Unmarshal(jsonBytes2, &msg)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

**Edit**:

If you want to convert those strings into specific types during the json unmarshaling, you can do so by defining an `UnmarshalJSON` method on the `*MsgRateQuoteJson` type, plus with the help of the `strconv` package, like this:

```
type MsgRateQuoteJson struct {
    SymbolName   string  `json:"Symbol"`
    SymbolBid    float64 `json:"Bid"`
    SymbolAsk    float64 `json:"Ask"`
    SymbolSpread float64 `json:"Spread"`
    SymbolPT     int64   `json:"ProductType"`
}

func (msg *MsgRateQuoteJson) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) (err error) {
    m := map[string]string{}
    if err = ffjson.Unmarshal(data, &m); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    msg.SymbolName = m["Symbol"]
    if msg.SymbolBid, err = strconv.ParseFloat(m["Bid"], 64); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if msg.SymbolAsk, err = strconv.ParseFloat(m["Ask"], 64); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if msg.SymbolSpread, err = strconv.ParseFloat(m["Spread"], 64); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if msg.SymbolPT, err = strconv.ParseInt(m["ProductType"], 10, 64); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: How could this be converted to floats and int not strings?

Comment: Are you sure you want ints and not floats? All those strings contain a floating point number...

Comment: Some are floats ( bid/ask/spread) and one is int (producttype) rest is string ( symbol )

Comment: Only problem with that func is it drops off symbol...only dose number conversion.

Comment: Good catch @user2777145, fixed it.

Comment: Is their a simple way to compare the current bid / ask result to previous bid / ask result and update current if their is a change?  What would be the simple way to do that.

Comment: You could hash the bytes, store the resulting hash, and next time you retrieve the bytes hash them as well and compare the new hash against the stored one. If you have problems with that you should open a new question.